# Problem with searchd protocol error in sphinx

Tags: sphinx, php4

I am getting the error

```
ERROR: expected searchd protocol version 1+, got version '0'.
```

Does anyone knows why is it coming so when i run test2.php of sphinx api(ver 0.9.9-win32).

Comment: Did you upgrade your version of the api without changing the version of searchd?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have started the `searchd` daemon. If not, find where you have the searchd installed, go to its directory and issue `./searchd` command.

Basically, follow [chapter 2.6 from the Sphinx manual](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#quick-tour)

Comment: thanks mloskot.but now i am getting 2 warnings.

WARNING: forcing --console mode on Windows

WARNING: seamless_rotate is not yet supported in windows; forcing seamless_rotate=0
listening on all interfaces, port=9312
accepting connections

Comment: @akku as far as I know, you can ignore it. It tells you didn't install searchd as a Windows service, you just control it manually.